# Memory efficient table of objects in Python

Tags: python

I have a big table/matrix (represented as list of lists). Each element of the table is a class object with data. Some of the elements are duplicating, and I want to ensure that my table requires as little memory as possible. I know that there are no pointers in Python, nevertheless class objects can be bonded to. I use the following syntax (as example):

```
x = y = 1000

my_table = [[None] * y for i in range(x)]

class MyDataClass:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2

def fill_fields(x1, x2, y1, y2, value1, value2):
    my_data = MyDataClass(value1, value2)
    for x in range(x1, x2):
        for y in range(y1, y2):
            my_table[x][y] = my_data

fill_fields(0, x, 0, y, 1, 2)
```

So, my question: does this syntax ensure that the duplicating object is written to memory in whole only once, and if not, what should I change?

P.S. I use Python3

Comment: Yes, your list will contain the same object x*y times. But why would you repeat same object so many times?

Comment: Well... In fact, he has pointer... You just don't see them. If you do `a = MyDataClass(); b = a` a and b point to the exact same instance. You can see it if you do `print(id(a), id(b))`. If you need do do a copy of an object you need to use service of the `copy` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to copy the same object into rectangular blocks, then your method should work.  Otherwise, it may be better to pass into the function an array of tuples, iterating over that array, and assigning each spot the class, rather than depend on only being able to do so in a x*y rectangle.

If you're really worried about memory efficiency, I would also look into [numpy.ndarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html).  It has "C-like" memory contiguous arrays, which should make arrays smaller, and give you the benefit of spacial locality, when iterating through them.

Comment: Thank you. Right now I work only with rectangles (1 * y, to be more precise). But in case I need something more sophisticated, I can also just appropriately modify the function, can't I?

Comment: @Roman *Arrays* in other words? This way you skip all the interesting test cases ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This way, the same object in `my_data` is referred to (x2-x1)*(y2-y1) times, but if you call the `fill_fields` function another time with the same values for `vaue1` and `value2`, then there will be multiple instances of `MyDataClass` (with the same "value") in your field.